# What's the best way to have multiple "setTimeout" in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, delay

I have different actions that needs to happen with a delay. This code works but I feel like it's not the best way to do it.
Does anyone have a recommendation?

```
$('.block-container').on('mouseout', function() {
    var $el = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
  $el.find('.block-values').removeClass('hover-rotate');
  $el.find('.text-under').removeClass('hover');
    }, 500);
});
$('.block-container').on('mouseout', function() {
    var $el = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
  $el.find('.values-text').removeClass('hover');
  $el.find('.plus-container').removeClass('hover');
    }, 600);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the second `setTimeout` inside the first instead of making two handlers.

```
$('.block-container').on('mouseout', function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    setTimeout(() => {
        $el.find('.block-values').removeClass('hover-rotate');
        $el.find('.text-under').removeClass('hover');
        setTimeout(() => {
            $el.find('.values-text').removeClass('hover');
            $el.find('.plus-container').removeClass('hover');
        }, 100)
    }, 500);
});
```

Another approach which might be easier to understand at a glance, by awaiting a delay function.

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
$('.block-container').on('mouseout', async function () {
    const $el = $(this);
    await delay(500);
    $el.find('.block-values').removeClass('hover-rotate');
    $el.find('.text-under').removeClass('hover');
    await delay(100);
    $el.find('.values-text').removeClass('hover');
    $el.find('.plus-container').removeClass('hover');
});
```